# Unable to workout how to create a class to deserialize into

Tags: c#, json, json.net

An API I am working with returns some data which I am struggling to work out how to build a class to deserialize it into.

I have become lazy of the years and, in Visual Studio, used the Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes.

This option has served me well over the years but has probably resulted in me not being skilled in doing it manually.

So, the data I have coming back looks like this in Fiddler:

[image]

As you can see, there are 3 competitors with results. I am trying to get to this data.

When I do my old faithful "Copy JSON as Classes" it results in this:

```
public class Competitor_Results
{
    public _36629 _36629 { get; set; }
    public _36628 _36628 { get; set; }
    public _36627 _36627 { get; set; }
}

public class _36629
{

    public string rank_type { get; set; }
    public int? rank { get; set; }
    public object position_places_image { get; set; }
    public int? position_organic { get; set; }
    public int? position_local_pack { get; set; }
    public object position_knowledge_panel { get; set; }
    public object position_featured_snippet { get; set; }
    public object[] position_change_cache { get; set; }
    public int last_week_change { get; set; }
    public int last_month_change { get; set; }
    public int last_day_change { get; set; }
}

public class _36628
{
    public string rank_type { get; set; }
    public int? rank { get; set; }
    public object position_places_image { get; set; }
    public int? position_organic { get; set; }
    public int? position_local_pack { get; set; }
    public object position_knowledge_panel { get; set; }
    public object position_featured_snippet { get; set; }
    public object[] position_change_cache { get; set; }
    public int last_week_change { get; set; }
    public int last_month_change { get; set; }
    public int last_day_change { get; set; }
}

public class _36627
{
    public string rank_type { get; set; }
    public int? rank { get; set; }
    public object position_places_image { get; set; }
    public int? position_organic { get; set; }
    public int? position_local_pack { get; set; }
    public int? position_knowledge_panel { get; set; }
    public object position_featured_snippet { get; set; }
    public object[] position_change_cache { get; set; }
    public int last_week_change { get; set; }
    public int last_month_change { get; set; }
    public int last_day_change { get; set; }
}
```

I can't work out what the class should look like to enable me to get 3 "Competitor Results" out and be re-usable for more/less results from other Competitors.

Can anyone give me some guidance please?

This is the JSON related to the "competitor results"

```
{
  "36629": {
    "rank_type": null,
    "rank": null,
    "position_places_image": null,
    "position_organic": null,
    "position_local_pack": null,
    "position_knowledge_panel": null,
    "position_featured_snippet": null,
    "position_change_cache": [
      null,
      "2019-03-21T19:23:06.177931Z"
    ],
    "last_week_change": 0,
    "last_month_change": 0,
    "last_day_change": 0
  },
  "36628": {
    "rank_type": "local_pack",
    "rank": 3,
    "position_places_image": null,
    "position_organic": 50,
    "position_local_pack": 3,
    "position_knowledge_panel": null,
    "position_featured_snippet": null,
    "position_change_cache": [
      null,
      "2019-03-21T19:23:06.178797Z"
    ],
    "last_week_change": 0,
    "last_month_change": 0,
    "last_day_change": 0
  },
  "36627": {
    "rank_type": "local_pack",
    "rank": 2,
    "position_places_image": null,
    "position_organic": 43,
    "position_local_pack": 2,
    "position_knowledge_panel": null,
    "position_featured_snippet": null,
    "position_change_cache": [
      null,
      "2019-03-20T20:25:35.263147Z"
    ],
    "last_week_change": 0,
    "last_month_change": 0,
    "last_day_change": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: use `object` instead user defined class

Comment: *use object instead user defined class* no... `Dictionary<int, Competitor_Result>  competitor_results` where  Competitor_Result has body of `_36629` or `_36628` or ... or maybe `Dictionary<string, Competitor_Result>  competitor_results` depends on key type

Comment: @PrashantPimpale how would `object` solve the problem at hand? OP could use a Dictionary or a list to store the values i.e. rename `public class _36628` to `competitor` and have `Competitor_Results` be a list.

Comment: @Selvin I am not sure about what front end he is using But I will use object and then retrieve the List of `Competitor_Results` and then iterate over it to get the key and value in the javascript (or will try!)

Comment: Show your json in text format and include all relevant classes so probably you will get best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most JSON class generators I've seen have trouble coping with this case, i.e. where the property name is dynamic.  After generating the code, you have a bunch of redundant class definitions (e.g. `_36628`, `_36629`, etc.) representing items and a container class (e.g. `Competitor_Results`) which has a reference to each one.

Here is how to fix the generated code:

1. Delete all the redundant item class definitions except one and then rename that one to something sensible, like `CompetitorResult`.
2. Replace the container class with `Dictionary<string, T>` where `T` is the name of your item class.  In other words, change the type of the property referencing the container class to `Dictionary<string, T>` and delete the container class itself.

You should end up with something like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    ...
    public Dictionary<string, CompetitorResult> competitor_results { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CompetitorResult
{
    public string rank_type { get; set; }
    public int? rank { get; set; }
    public object position_places_image { get; set; }
    public int? position_organic { get; set; }
    public int? position_local_pack { get; set; }
    public object position_knowledge_panel { get; set; }
    public object position_featured_snippet { get; set; }
    public object[] position_change_cache { get; set; }
    public int last_week_change { get; set; }
    public int last_month_change { get; set; }
    public int last_day_change { get; set; }
}
```